# Filemaker: how to parse a path?

Tags: filemaker

I can't figure out how I get only the directory of an image by a Filemaker calculation.

Eg, from the path:

```
file://Macintosh HD/Users/user1/Documents/Clients/client1/project/phase/research/test6/images/subdir/090420/090422.jpg
```

I only would need `090420` to put in a field.

Can anyone explain how I would do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how I get only the directory of an image

To get the *enclosing* directory of the file (i.e. the next-to-last step of the given path), try:

```
Let ( 
steps = Substitute ( path ; "/", ¶ ) 
; 
GetValue ( steps ; ValueCount ( steps ) - 1 )
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. These hints help me a lot to advance in Filemaker, thank you :)

Comment: This is indeed a good solution.  The Let variable "steps" creates a return separated list.  The GetValue function then returns the second to last value.  This works regardless of the length of the path provided the result desired is the 2nd to last value.  Easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Elegant. I would usually calculate the position of last two "/" and use Middle(), but this is much better.